# Convert a list into a Numpy array lose two of its three axis only with one dataset

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, simpleitk, nifti

I have a python code that reads NIFTI images using SimpleITK library. Then it converts that images into a Numpy Array. Then, I extend the Numpy Array into a list.

I have 20 FLAIR.nii.gz files. Each of them have 48 slices.

When I have all the 48 slices of all the 20 patients, I convert the list into a Numpy Array.

I do it this way because I'm newbie with Python and I don't know any other way to do it.

The code is:

```
import os
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np

flair_dataset = []

# For each patient directory
# data_path is a list with all of the patient's directory.
for i in data_path:

    img_path = os.path.join(file_path, i, 'pre')
    mask_path = os.path.join(file_path, i)

    for name in glob.glob(img_path+'/FLAIR*'):
        # Reads images using SimpleITK.
        brain_image = sitk.ReadImage(name)
        # Get a numpy array from a SimpleITK Image.
        brain_array = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(brain_image)

        flair_dataset.extend(brain_array)

        if debug:
            print('brain_image size: ', brain_image.GetSize())
            print('brain_array Shape: ', brain_array.shape)
            print('flair_dataset length:', len(flair_dataset))

print('flair_dataset length: ', len(flair_dataset))
print('flair_dataset[1] type: ', print(type(flair_dataset[1])))
print('flair_dataset[1] shape: ', print(flair_dataset[1].shape))

flair_array = np.array(flair_dataset)
print('flair_array.shape: ', flair_array.shape)
print('flair_array.dtype: ', flair_array.dtype)
```

This code generates this output (all FLAIR.nii.gz files have the same shape):

```
data_path =  ['68', '55', '50', '61', '63', '52', '51', '60', '67', '58', '59', '53', '69', '64', '56', '65', '54', '62', '66', '57']
patient_data_path =  68
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 48
Mask list length:  48

patient_data_path =  55
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 96
Mask list length:  96

patient_data_path =  50
brain_image size:  (256, 232, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 232, 256)
flair_dataset length: 144
WMH image Size:  (256, 232, 48)
WMH array Shape:  (48, 232, 256)
Mask list length:  144

patient_data_path =  61
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 192
Mask list length:  192

patient_data_path =  63
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 240
Mask list length:  240

patient_data_path =  52
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 288
Mask list length:  288

patient_data_path =  51
brain_image size:  (256, 232, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 232, 256)
flair_dataset length: 336
WMH image Size:  (256, 232, 48)
WMH array Shape:  (48, 232, 256)
Mask list length:  336

patient_data_path =  60
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 384
Mask list length:  384

patient_data_path =  67
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 432
Mask list length:  432

patient_data_path =  58
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 480
Mask list length:  480

patient_data_path =  59
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 528
Mask list length:  528

patient_data_path =  53
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 576
Mask list length:  576

patient_data_path =  69
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 624
Mask list length:  624

patient_data_path =  64
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 672
Mask list length:  672

patient_data_path =  56
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 720
Mask list length:  720

patient_data_path =  65
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 768
Mask list length:  768

patient_data_path =  54
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 816
Mask list length:  816

patient_data_path =  62
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 864
Mask list length:  864

patient_data_path =  66
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 912
Mask list length:  912

patient_data_path =  57
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
flair_dataset length: 960
Mask list length:  960
```

The final output from the code is:

```
flair_dataset length:  960
mask_dataset length:  960
flair_dataset[1] type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
flair_dataset[1] shape:  (256, 232)
flair_array.shape:  (960,)
flair_array.dtype:  object
```

My problem:

I don't understand why flair_array has this shape: `(960,)`. 
`flair_array dtype` is `object`.

I have tried the same code, without changing anything, and it works perfectly. It has 20 patients also, and 48 slices for each FLAIR.nii.gz file also.

Its output:

```
data_path =  ['39', '31', '2', '23', '35', '29', '17', '49', '27', '8', '33', '4', '19', '41', '37', '11', '25', '6', '0', '21']

patient_data_path =  39
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 48
Mask list length:  48

patient_data_path =  31
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 96
Mask list length:  96

patient_data_path =  2
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 144
Mask list length:  144

patient_data_path =  23
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 192
Mask list length:  192

patient_data_path =  35
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 240
Mask list length:  240

patient_data_path =  29
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 288
Mask list length:  288

patient_data_path =  17
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 336
Mask list length:  336

patient_data_path =  49
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 384
Mask list length:  384

patient_data_path =  27
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 432
Mask list length:  432

patient_data_path =  8
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 480
Mask list length:  480

patient_data_path =  33
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 528
Mask list length:  528

patient_data_path =  4
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 576
Mask list length:  576

patient_data_path =  19
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 624
Mask list length:  624

patient_data_path =  41
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 672
Mask list length:  672

patient_data_path =  37
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 720
Mask list length:  720

patient_data_path =  11
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 768
Mask list length:  768

patient_data_path =  25
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 816
Mask list length:  816

patient_data_path =  6
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 864
Mask list length:  864

patient_data_path =  0
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 912
Mask list length:  912

patient_data_path =  21
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
flair_dataset length: 960
Mask list length:  960
```

This is the final output for this dataset:

```
flair_dataset length:  960
mask_dataset length:  960
flair_dataset[1] type:  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
flair_dataset[1] shape:  (240, 240)
flair_array.shape:  (960, 240, 240)
flair_array.dtype:  float32
```

With this second dataset the `flair_array` is `float32`.

Why the first `flair_array` shape is `(960,)`?

**UPDATE:**
In both datasets, `brain_array.dtype` is `float32` always.

Comment: Check the `dtype`.  Is one `object` and the other numeric (or string)?  Look at some of the values.  `shape` is only one metric.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks but I don't understand you. Where do I have to check the dtype? I'm don't understand also this: " Is one object and the other numeric (or string)? " Thanks.

Comment: `flair_array.dtype` etc.

Comment: @hpaulj For the first dataset, `flair_array.dtype` is `object`, for the second dataset is `float32`. I have updated my question with dtype output.

Comment: @hpaulj In both datasets, `brain_array.dtype` is `float32`. `brain_array` is the array that I extends into the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one case

```
flair_array.shape:  (960,)
flair_array.dtype:  object
```

in the other

```
flair_array.shape:  (960, 240, 240)
flair_array.dtype:  float32
```

You make these with:

```
flair_array = np.array(flair_dataset)
```

If all the elements of `flair_dataset` have the same shape, it can create a multidimensional array from them.

But if one or more of the arrays in the list differ in shape, it has to give up on the multidimensional goal, and instead just makes an object dtype array, which is very much like a list - in contains references to the original arrays.

In the original list most of the elements are

```
brain_image size:  (232, 256, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 256, 232)
```

but I also see some

```
brain_image size:  (256, 232, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 232, 256)
```

In the second set all are

```
brain_image size:  (240, 240, 48)
brain_array Shape:  (48, 240, 240)
```

When people ask about a (n,) shape, when they expect (n,m,p), I suspect the first has an `object` dtype caused by a mix in element shapes.  That's why I asked about `dtype`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that that `flair_dataset.extend(brain_array)` is just extending the the flair_dataset list with the loaded array.
So that in the `flair_dataset` there is on array with all the 960 images stacked. Each Image has the size of 240, 240.

Are you loading the images in Batches, or contains on image the depth of 48 layers? 
If so try to append the array and not extending it. Then it you put the loaded array in its on list entry.

Comment: I think you are right, and the number 960 comes from stacking 20 image with 48 slices 20 x 48 = 960

Comment: Each FLAIR.nii.gz file has 48 slices. I read 20 FLAIR.nii.gz files, one after other in the for loop. Sorry, but your answer doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Okay, then I don't get your question. Didn't you ask, why the shape is (960, ...) ?